# MongoDB Query if nested boolean is true

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB Mongoose events schema that looks in part like this.

```
...
  details: {
    startDate: String,
    endDate: String,
    startTime: Number,
    endTime: Number,
    days: {
      monday: Boolean,
      tuesday: Boolean,
      wednesday: Boolean,
      thursday: Boolean,
      friday: Boolean,
      saturday: Boolean,
      sunday: Boolean,
    },
  },
...
```

I need to query events that are happening that day, that is, events that have the start date as that day, or events that have the start date at a past date and the end date at a future date, and the weekday is true for that particular day.
For instance a Happy Friday event, that takes place every Friday, the start date is 1st January 2017 and the end date 31st December 2017, how can I query that it appears every Friday of the year?

This is what I have, and I'm kinda lost now. (Using moment and Mongoose)

```
const todayDateISO = moment().startOf('d').add(1, 'd').toISOString();
const todayDay = moment().startOf('d').add(1, 'd').format('dddd');

Event.find({
  $or: [
    { 'details.startDate': todayDateISO },
    {
      $and: [
        {
          $and: [
            { 'details.startDate': { $lte: todayDateISO } },
            { 'details.endDate': { $gte: todayDateISO } },
          ],
        },
        {
          // details.days.[day] is true
        }
      ]
    },
  ],
}).sort({ 'profile.startTime': 1 }).exec(),
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What's the format of `startDate` and `endDate` (YYYY-MM-DD / DD-MM-YYYY) ? They should be of `Date` type

Comment: @BertrandMartel graphQL doesn't have a date type and it's what I use to query, so I save them as an ISO string, e.g `new Date().toISOString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your schema to just store days as array

Something like `days: [String]` with values `days:["Friday", "Monday"]` and try below query.

```
Event.find({
  $or: [
    { 'details.startDate': todayDateISO },   
    {  $and:
        [ 
           { 'details.startDate': { $lte: todayDateISO } },
           { 'details.endDate': { $gte: todayDateISO } },
           { 'details.days': todayDay  }
        ] 
    }
  ]
}).sort({ 'profile.startTime': 1 }).exec()
```